# Reset xAxis[0] and xAxis[1] width in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a quick question for you re Highcharts.

How do I reset xAxis[0] and xAxis[1] width at runtime, and how do I also reset xAxis[1] offset at runtime? Reason I am asking is because I have a chart harbouring two x-axes and these need to be resized to fit differently sized divs. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/F3pts/7/

More generally speaking I struggle to reset options at runtime. I understand there are "setOptions" that can define general options for the chart, but that these are then 'trumped' by chart options when the chart is drawn. I however don't always get it how these options can be changed once the chart has already been drawn once. Something like:

```
newOptions({
chart:{},
xAxis:[{},{}],
etc....
});
```

Hope you don't think this is a poor quality question. I have trawled through heaps of material on this and cannot find the answer to my needs.

Rgds,
G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple use `Axis.update(newOptions)`, [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update).

Where you can set new `width`/`height`/`offset` etc.

Comment: Pawel, you have just opened a whole new world for me. You have no idea what crazy contortions I had been doing to reset some options.

Comment: Quick question -how do I check if there is a secondary x-axis? I want to reset the axes ONLY if there is a xAxis[0]? Thank you so much, Sir.

Comment: I would just check length of the `chart.xAxis` array. If length = 2, then you have two xAxes. Don't forget to accept answer ;)